# Phase space for systems with varying number of particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I'm currently studying statistical mechanics and having a hard time going conceptually from the *canonical ensemble* to the *gran canonical ensemble*. Up until now I've been studying only *ensembles* with a fixed number of particles therefore I've been thinking about the system's state as living in a 6N-dimentional phase space. Moreover the probability density function for the *ensemble* was a function on phase space.

Where does the state of a system with a varying number of particles live in? What's the equivalent of phase space for the *gran canonical ensemble*? How is the *ergodic hypothesis* formulated in this new space?

Comment: Since the number of particles can be any whole number, there is no single usual $6N$-dimensional phase space. Instead, the grand canonical ensemble refers to a probability distribution describing all possibilities $N=0,N=1,...$, thus one can say all possible phase spaces for all possible sets of particles are considered. The resulting "superspace" of states the control volume can be in is kind of similar to what the Fock space is in quantum theory - possible states describe all possible numbers of particles in all possible single-particle states.

Comment: So basically you work on the union of all possible phase spaces as N goes from $0$ to $+\infty$. A measure for this set can be easily defined so I guess integrating the probability density function would not be a problem. Tough, how to generalize the ergodic hypothesis is still unclear...

Comment: Why would you want to "generalize the ergodic hypothesis"? It originated in mathematics of isolated systems. Already canonical ensemble describes a system interacting with a heat reservoir. Ergodicity seems immaterial to this description.

Comment: About the ergodic hypothesis I think you are right: the question doesn't make sense since the hypothesis is specif for micro-canonical (isolated) ensembles. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct phase space $X$ of a classical system describing an arbitrary number of identical particles is
$$
X = \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \mathbb{R}^{6n},
$$
where $\coprod$ denotes the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Set_theory_definition). An element of $X$ has the form $(n,x)$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is the number of particles and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{6n}$ is the vector of momenta/positions of the $n$ particles.

Now there is not a single probability density function. Instead there is a function $\rho_n : \mathbb{R}^{6n} \to [0,\infty)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
such that the probability $P(n,\Gamma)$ to observe the system consisting of $n$ particles with their momenta and positions in the phase space volume $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^{6n}$ is
$$
P(n,\Gamma) = \int_\Gamma \rho_n (x) dx^{6n}.
$$

Note that the normalisation condition here is, that
$$
1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^{6n}} \rho_n (x) dx^{6n},
$$
i.e. the probability of observing any number of particles with any position and momenta is 1.

I am not sure about the "ergodic hypothesis" in this context, maybe you can elaborate what exactly the "ergodic hypothesis" means to you.

---

Elaborating on the ideas discussed in the comments (in particular HTNW's comment):

In the case of multiple kind (species) of particles the phase space can be constructed as follows:

Let $S$ be the (finite) set of species. Define the state space $X$ of a classical system describing an arbitrary number of particles from different species (from $S$) as
$$
X = \prod_{s \in S} \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}^{6n}.
$$
So an element of $X$ (a state of the system) is a tuple of the form $(n_s,x_s)_{s \in S}$, where $n_s$ is the number of particles of species $s$ in the state and $x_s$ is the vector storing positions and momenta of these $n_s$ particles.

A probability measure can be constructed on this space by considering the product of the probability measures defined above for each species.

Comment: Do you mean indistinguishable or distinguishable particles? For indistinguishable particles, one has to impose further restrictions on $\rho_n$. For $n$ distinguishable particles, one should consider all possible phase spaces  $\mathbb{R}^{6n}$, there is not just one.

Comment: @JánLalinský The particles are supposed to be of the same species. Different species can be incorporated by taking an additional disjoint union over all present species.

Comment: @JánLalinský That being said i do not understand your comment and how it relates to my answer/ the grand canoncial ensemble of a classical system at all, please elaborate.

Comment: You use $\mathbb R^{6n}$ to refer to a phase space of $n$ particles, but there are many different spaces of such dimension, for different sets of particles.

Comment: Still I don't get how this space takes into account the fact that if the particles are distinguishable which particles "are missing" and which "are present" matters. Does it make sense to talk about a system with varying number of particles if the particles are distinguishable?

Comment: @HomoVafer The space $X$ can only describe a system of identical particles (same species). Since for these their labeling has no effect on the physics. Like i wrote above, if we allow multiple kinds of particle, then we need to take another disjoint union over all present kind of particles. We then describe the state by $(s,n,x)$ where $s$ is the species, $n$ the number of particles of species $s$ that are present and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{3n}$ are the positions and momenta of the present particles of species $s$.

Comment: @jd27 You would take a *product* over the species and a sum over the numbers, no? The state space for a system with varying particle numbers where each particle has a species (from a set $S$ of species) will be $X=\prod_{s\in S}\coprod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb R^{6n}.$ A state will be a vector $(n_1,x_1,\ldots,n_s,x_s)$ where $n_i$ is the number of particles of the species indexed with $i$ and $x_i$ are the coordinates of those particles. Alternatively, the state is a function from the set of species to the set described in the answer.

Comment: Also (a nit): I note that it's quite traditional, at least in math, to write the components of a pair living in a coproduct in the same order as the coproduct is written. $X=\coprod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb R^{6n}$ is the space of pairs $(n, x)$ where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in\mathbb R^{6n}.$ Why do you write them the other way around—is that common in mechanics?

Comment: @HTNW You are totally right, it should be the product over the species. I didnt think that one through!

Comment: I think the expression for $X$ is correct but I don't think you need to specify $n_i$ in the state vector: once you choose $x_i$ you know how many particles of kind $i$ there are since there will always be one and only one $n_i$ such that $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{6n_i}$. If all particles are distinguishable than every particle is of a different kind than $S = \mathbb{N}$, right?

Comment: With all particles distinguishable I would use $X = \prod_{s\in\mathbb{N}} (\{\Box\} \cup \mathbb{R}^6)$ where $\Box$ is the state of non-existence.